# Target with AfterTargets="Publish" executes in unpublishable project

Tags: msbuild, .net-5

I have a project in my solution that I wanna publish separately from the rest of the solution. So the way to skip it is by setting the `IsPublishable` property to false, which works like a charm. It seems though that no matter the publishable status of the project, targets set to run after the publish target (`AfterTargets="Publish"`) are still executed when I try to publish the entire solution.

Is this intended? Is there any way to prevent this? I am using VS 2022 preview.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <BaseOutputPath>..\Build</BaseOutputPath>
    <IsPublishable>false</IsPublishable>
    
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <SomeFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)SomeFiles\**\*.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>


    <Target Name="CopyCustomContentBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(SomeFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)SomeFiles" />
        <Message Text="Files copied successfully." Importance="high" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CopyCustomContentPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(SomeFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)SomeFiles" />
        <Message Text="Files copied successfully to publish dir." Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the intended behaviour. When you set `IsPublishable` to `false` MsBuild still logs when a Publish target is supposed to run and continues onto your `AfterTargets="Publish"` target.

You'll have to set a condition on your actions inside the target to make sure they do not get executed when IsPublishable is false.

```
 <Target Name="CopyCustomContentPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SomeFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)SomeFiles" Condition=" '$(IsPublishable)' == 'true' " />
    <Message Text="Files copied successfully to publish dir." Importance="high" Condition=" '$(IsPublishable)' == 'true' " />
</Target>
```